# Filter Collection of strings by typing substring with '%' char

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having problem with creating regular expression which would map sql server `like` clause.

Let's take an example:

There is string **C2-513101-0045** in my collection and I would like to filter my collection to get this string by typing e.g : **C2-%-0045** or **C2-51%** etc.

I've tried this...

```
public static class MyStringExtensions
{
    public static bool Like(this string toSearch, string toFind)
    {
        return new Regex(@"\A" + new Regex(@"\.|\$|\^|\{|\[|\(|\||\)|\*|\+|\?|\\").Replace(toFind, ch => @"\" + ch).Replace('_', '.').Replace("%", ".*") + @"\z", RegexOptions.Singleline).IsMatch(toSearch);
    }
}
```

... and also tried to modify it. No results.

How to achieve filtering strings "sql-like" ?

Comment: `var result = Regex.Matches("C2-###-0045", "C2-%-0045".Replace("%","(.*)"))` it looks like it's working with a simple replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static class MyStringExtensions
{
    public static bool Like(this string toSearch, string toFind)
    {
        Regex findRegex = new Regex(Regex.Escape(toFind).Replace("%", ".*"));
        return findRegex.IsMatch(toSearch);
    }
}
```

Try the above method. First I have escaped all meta-characters using `Regex.Escape`. Then replace `%` by `.*`